# R Cross join on ff object

Tags: r

I am using ff package and trying to do cross join. I know ffdf merge performs only inner and left outer join. Is there any tweak where I can do cross join.

```
a=as.ffdf(data.frame(a=1:10,b=11:20))
z=as.ffdf(data.frame(y=2:4))
```

Please help me to `cross join a and z ff object.`

Thanks

Comment: One way to use `ffdfappend function with loop.` This will work like cross join.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of expand.ffgrid and merge.ffdf from package ffbase.

```
require(ff)
a=as.ffdf(data.frame(a=1:10,b=11:20))
z=as.ffdf(data.frame(y=2:4))

require(ffbase)
a$a.key <- ikey(a)
z$z.key <- ikey(z)
combined <- expand.ffgrid(a.key = a$a.key, z.key = z$z.key)
combined <- merge(combined, a, by.x="a.key", by.y="a.key", all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
combined <- merge(combined, z, by.x="z.key", by.y="z.key", all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
```

Comment: Getting memory error while running expand.ffgrid with big data set.

Comment: With expand.ffgrid? Can you make a reproducible example where that occurs. I can run this on a 32-bit computer with 2Gb of RAM to get an ffdf with 1billion rows. require(ffbase); a <- ffseq_len(1000); b <- ffseq_len(1000000); x <- expand.ffgrid(a, b);